# Shell variables in a for loop

Tags: bash, variable, for

I have a difficulty getting over this `man bash` passage.

> If the control variable in a `for` loop has the `nameref` attribute, the list of words can be a list of shell variables, and  a name reference will be established for each word in the list, in turn, when the loop is executed.
>
> Array variables cannot be given the `-n` attribute. However, `nameref` variables can reference array variables and subscripted array variables.

Could you give an example of this `nameref` variable in a loop with some explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nameref variable is to a “normal” variable what a symbolic link is to a regular file.

```
$ typeset -n ref=actual; ref=foo; echo "$actual"
foo
```

A for loop executes the body with the loop variable (the “control variable”) bound in turn to each word in the list.

```
$ for x in one two three; do echo "$x"; done
one
two
three
```

This is equivalent to writing out successive assignments:

```
x=one; echo "$x"
x=two; echo "$x"
x=three; echo "$x"
```

If the loop variable is a nameref, then the body is executed with the nameref targeting each element of the word list in turn. This is not equivalent to a series of assignment like above: an assignment `ref=value` where `ref` is a nameref would affect the variable that `ref` is pointing to, but the for loop changes where the nameref points rather than following the reference to change the variable that it points to.

```
$ original=0; one=1; two=2; three=3
$ typeset -n ref=original
$ echo $ref
0
$ for ref in one two three; do echo "$ref"; done
1
2
3
$ echo original
0
```

The indirection can be observed through assignments as well, if you assign to the loop variable (which is uncommon, but permitted).

```
$ one=1; two=2; three=3
$ typeset -n ref
$ for ref in one two three; do echo ref=$((ref+10)); done
$ echo "$one $two $three"
11 12 13
```

The last sentence explains that the target of a nameref can be an array. The nameref itself isn't an array, it's still a scalar variable, but when it's used in an assignment or in a dereference, it acts as the same type as the variable it points to.

```
$ a=(0 1 2)
$ typeset -n ref=a
$ ref[1]=changed
$ echo "${a[@]}"
0 changed 2
```