# Dynamic variable references

Tags: bash, variable

I want to define a variable `my_stacklist` with the value for `{mypc}_stacklist`
so if `mypc=kast` I get to access the content of `kast_stacklist` via `my_stacklist`.

I thougt this was the same as my earlier questions about dynamic variables , but cant fix it with `declare` or `eval`.

I use bash on a RPi 4 with the latest OS.

```bash
# want to have a my_stacklist for the current mypc and associating stacklist {mypc}_stacklist
mypc=kast
kast_stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 stack4 )
screen_stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 )

# First attempt
xxxx=$(eval "echo ${mypc}_stacklist") 
my_stacklist=$(eval "echo \$$xxxx")
printf "my_stacklist=${my_stacklist[@]}"

# Second attempt
#declare -n my_stacklist2=${xxxx[@]}        
declare -n my_stacklist2=${xxxx}        
printf "my_stacklist=${my_stacklist[@]}"
# i only get the first item instead of all items
```

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: My bash version is  5.1.4

Comment: I am a lithe further, but my script stills does not work
 #stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 stack4 )
 #kast_stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 stack4 )
 #screen_stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 )

 my_stacklist=(${mypc}_stacklist[@])
 echo ${!my_stacklist}
looks like my_stacklist is not the same format as stacklist that is currently used..
i want to make more stacklist, for each server on, so thats why i made kast_stacklist and screen_stacklist. Idea is to make a fixed variable that picks the right one based on $mypc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell variables in a for loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351260/shell-variables-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nameref:

```bash
mypc=kast
kast_stacklist=(k1 k2 k3)
other_stacklist=(o1 o2 o3)

declare -n mystacklist="${mypc}_stacklist"

for i in "${!mystacklist[@]}"; do
  printf '%d\t%s\n' $i "${mystacklist[i]}"
done
```

```
0   k1
1   k2
2   k3
```

Comment: that one is better then the trial i did last hours

 i=1
 foo_kast=(fff ddd) ;
 foo_screen=(ggg ccc) ;
 kast_foo=(fff ddd) ;
 screen_foo=(ggg ccc) ;
 eval my_stacklist1=( \${foo_$mypc[@]} ) ;
 eval my_stacklist2=( \${${mypc}_foo[@]} ) ;
 echo ${my_stacklist1[$i]};
 echo ${my_stacklist2[$i]};
 echo ${my_stacklist1[@]};
 echo ${my_stacklist2[@]};